# How do you say "walked from....to...."

Tags: translation

For example, would it be: 我从我的家到教室走路。?

I know how to say simply "from somewhere to somewhere" but I'm not sure where you put the verb if you want to say like "walked from somewhere to someone"

Comment: 从家走到学校. similarly `go from X to Y by bike` is `从X骑车到Y`

Answer (score 10):

[Subject] + 从/由 (from) + [source] + [verb or phrase for the appropriate mode of travel] + 到 (to) + [destination].

我从家里走到教室 I walked from home to the classroom.

我从家里搭公车到学校 I took a bus from home to school.

失明机师由英国飞到澳洲 Blind pilot flies from UK to Australia. (News headline)

Answer (score 5):

I'm reading the previous answers, I am adding this one for fulfilling your initial interest which is to translate

```
walked from somewhere to _someone_
```

The trick in Chinese language consists of transforming someone into a destination, which is needed after some complements (e.g., 在, 到). 
For doing this you use a place specifier (e.g., 那儿， 这儿) after the pronoun, as in the example

```
我要去她那儿。
```

So I would translate your sentence as:

```
我 从 家里 走到 她那儿。
```

which can also be written, if you already know the place she is:

```
我 从 家里 走到 她家。
```

Of course replacing the place you start, the way you go (e.g., 骑自行车， 走路， 开车) , the place she/he is. Just a final remark, in case you need to translate somewhere, you can use 哪里 as in 他在哪里。Note that this is not an interrogative.

Answer (score 3):

我**从**家里**走到**教室。

I walked from my house to my class(room).

Answer (score 1):

walked from somewhere **to** someone ： 去哪**找**某人。
"to" translate "找".
   ha-ha, i'm a Chinese, know Chinese, but English is bad.

Answer (score 1):

“from…to…” in Chinese would be "从。。。到。。。"

“walked from…to…” in Chinese would be "从。。。走(路)到。。。"

So it is 我从我的家走(路)到教室. Remember, Chinese sentence structure is very straightforward, which is mostly S + V + O, even in a question sentence.